# ElasticSearch asynchronous post

Tags: database, post, asynchronous, elasticsearch, get

I'm posting data on my ElasticSearch database.

I've noticed that data is not immediately available, it requires some milliseconds to show up in a GET request. I can live with that (after all, the calls are asynchronous so this behavior is expected) but in my test code I need to POST some data and immediately after retrieve it. At the moment I'm using a sleep(5) just to be sure data is available but how can I synchronize with the db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure data is available, you can make a `refresh` request to corresponding index before GET/SEARCH:

```
http://localhost:9200/your_index/_refresh
```

Or refresh all indexes:

```
http://localhost:9200/_refresh
```